# How to name an Ancient Egyptian Prince?

Tags: culture, language, ancient-history, names

I have created a character and only still need his name. I've spent the past 3-4 hours googling stuff about Ancient Egyptian royal naming conventions, and it's a lot! @_@

The character is a young man (25-26 years old) and a prince--but he's very low on the inheritance scale, as he has multiple older brothers. I have him roughly pegged as Nebhepetre Mentuhotep II's son and Sankhkare Mentuhotep III's younger half-brother.

Based on what I read, Egyptian royalty had ~5 names. "The Horus (Name 1)," "The Son of Re (Name 2)" -- the name at birth, which is the name scholars today use, "King of Upper and Lower Egypt (Name 3)" -- which is a name they take when they take the throne, and two other names that aren't written down as much as the first three.

***My dilemma is that I need a working "Son of Re"/birth name--a name that ISN'T the name of an existing historical figure. That would be the character's real name.***

But I ALSO need a name he lies about, because due to things in the plot, he's going to lie and claim he actually stands a chance at inheriting the throne, which would be reflected in the name he lies and picks for himself. This would probably be a second "Son of Re" name or the "King of Upper and Lower Egypt" name he claims he'll use when he takes the throne (that he really has no chance of inheriting). Am I making sense?

From what I've read, Egyptian names are composed of two or three parts to make a phrase (sort of like Japanese names are). Like "Khafra" combines 'to appear' with 'Ra,' meaning "Ra appears." But all the parts and pieces I try to stick together myself don't create any name Google recognizes. I'd like the name to include the meaning for "father" (due to the character's daddy issues) or something involving the name of a god, like Thoth or Ra, due to his rather grandiose personality.

I'm sorry if this is long or confusing. My eyes are a bit crossed after hours of research.

The TL;DR is: I need help with Ancient Egyptian naming conventions to name an original character without calling him after an actual historical figure. Any help from someone who knows ancient Egypt(ian) is appreciated--as is anyone who can point me to, useful sources about creating Egyptian names or of Egyptian princes who never actually took the throne.

Comment: Names are incredibly arbitrary things. Since any new historical discovery will invalidate existing answers asking for a name isn't a suitable question for this site. We also have a requirement that questions on this site are specific about what they ask for. Can you [edit] this post to focus on a specific resource type? Perhaps you could ask for a list of historical Egyptian names, and make up something not on that list.

Comment: @Sphennings Asking just for a list of historical Egyptian names is about history of names, not really worldbuilding ^^. So hard to ask about names here...

Comment: To me, it looks like you're more stuck at making a choice as an author (off-topic here since opinion-based), rather than on naming conventions you seem to have already learned quite a lot now . I think you're on a good path when setting clear intentions, it focuses on what you truly want to tell. Also, know that the "too famous/too common" feelings grow stronger the longer you think on the name and/or know the topic (you get accustomed to it). To circumvent this you could gain from external inputs -friends, colleagues...-, see what they link or not the name to :).

Comment: @Tortliena Sorry I should have been clearer. Asking for us to construct a list, ourselves would be an inappropriate question. Asking us to provide links to worldbuilding resources like [wikipedia's list of historic egyptians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ancient_Egyptians) I'd argue is an appropriate ask. It's the difference between the text of the answer being a list of things, and the text of an answer being a reference to some external pre-existing list of things, as well as an explanation about why said list satisfies OP's needs.

Comment: A bit of vocab: once they attain the throne, rulers gain all kinds of special titles that are not actually part of their name but which nevertheless are always included whenever the monarch's name appears. This is described as "style," as in this [quote about Charles III](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_III#Titles,_styles,_honours_and_arms): "Charles was originally styled 'His Royal Highness Prince Charles of Edinburgh'." Your description makes me think the situation was very much the same for pharaohs.

Answer (score 6):

In most , almost all, ancient cultures names were meaningful two or three word phrases. (The only notable exception are the Romans, but with the Romans it is easy -- there are less than two dozen possible given names for boys, and girls did not have given names at all.)

The problem is that I know very very little about Ancient Egyptian... You must find somebody who knows Ancient Egyptian and ask them to translate a short phrase of your choice. (And of course Google doesn't recognize it if it is not an actual name of an actual pharaoh. How could it? Google doesn't know Ancient Egyptian.)

The five-name formula was used only for pharaohs, and, since your hero is not a pharaoh, he won't have or use this kind of formula. (Think of *His Majesty Charles the Third, by the Grace of God, of the United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland and of His other Realms and Territories King, Head of the Commonwealth, Defender of the Faith* -- only actual sovereigns use such a style.) He will have only one name, assigned to him by his father at birth, which, *if* he ever becomes pharaoh, would become his personal (a.k.a. son of Ra) name.

My suggestion is to invest some time and compile a list of names of lesser-known Egyptians, together with their meanings. Then pick one of them. Start for example with Wikipedia's [list of ancient Egyptians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ancient_Egyptians), or go to a library and pick up a nice thick book about Ancient Egypt.

Addaya — Amenemhat — Amenemhatankh — Amenemipet — Amenemope — Amenmose — Ankhefensekhmet — Ankherfenedjef — Ankhhaf — Ankhkherednefer — Ankhtifi — Ankhu — Aperel — Bakenkhonsu — Bakenrenef — Baqet — Djedefhor — Djediufankh — Djedptahiufankh — Djehutihotep — Djehuty — Djehutynakht — Hannu — Hapuseneb — Haremakhet — Harkhebi — Harkhuf — Harwa — Hemaka — Hemiunu — Hepu — Heqaib — Heqanakht — Hesy-Ra — Hewernef — Horbaef — Hornakht — Ibiaw — Inkaef — Intefiqer — Isesi-ankh — Kaemqed — Kaemsekhem — Kagemni etc. etc.

Comment: The thing I find particularly useful about this answer is that it highlights the fact that a reigning monarch's name only becomes complex _upon attaining the throne_. This wanna-be pharaoh will not have all 5 parts of a proper pharaonic name.